# Simulate Dealing card in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am making function for poker hand(dealing cards to 'n' players).
I am trying to simulate card dealing function in my codeigniter. but I am stuck, because all players getting same card pairs.

Here is my Model function:

```
$deck = array(
    'AD', '2D', '3D', '4D', '5D', '6D', '7D', '8D', '9D', 'TD', 'JD', 'QD', 'KD',
    'AC', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', 'JC', 'QC', 'KC',
    'AH', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H', '6H', '7H', '8H', '9H', 'TH', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH',
    'AS', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', '8S', '9S', 'TS', 'JS', 'QS', 'KS'
);

shuffle($deck);

$player_card = array();

$cycle = 2;
for ($k=0; $k < $players; $k++) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $cycle; $i++) { 
        $player_card[$k][$i] = $deck[$i];   
    }
}
```

I am Getting output like this:

this is shuffled deck:

```
Array
(
    [0] => JC
    [1] => AC
    [2] => 4H
    [3] => 5D
    [4] => 3D
    [5] => QD
    [6] => 7H
    [7] => 8S
    [8] => AD
    [9] => KD
    [10] => 6C
    [11] => KH
    [12] => TS
    [13] => 8D
    [14] => 7S
    [15] => 9C
    [16] => 6D
    [17] => 6S
    [18] => 4S
    [19] => KC
    [20] => 2H
    [21] => 9H
    [22] => 8H
    [23] => 2C
    [24] => AS
    [25] => 7C
    [26] => 3C
    [27] => 2D
    [28] => QS
    [29] => QC
    [30] => JS
    [31] => JH
    [32] => 9D
    [33] => TC
    [34] => 3S
    [35] => 4C
    [36] => 2S
    [37] => 3H
    [38] => JD
    [39] => 5H
    [40] => 6H
    [41] => AH
    [42] => TH
    [43] => TD
    [44] => KS
    [45] => 9S
    [46] => 8C
    [47] => 5S
    [48] => 7D
    [49] => 4D
    [50] => 5C
    [51] => QH
)
```

this is 'n' Player's card(n = 3)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => JC
            [1] => AC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => JC
            [1] => AC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => JC
            [1] => AC
        )

)
```

What I want in out Put is:
want to make turn based assignment of cards to each players.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => JC
                [1] => 5D
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => AC
                [1] => 3D
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4H
                [1] => QD
            )

    )
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @taha Paksu:

**array_chunk()** wored for me. I managed it according to my need.

Here is the complete model for 'N' players card dealing logic.

```
class Card_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function shuffled_deck($type, $players)
    {
        $noraml_deck = $deck = array(
            'AD', '2D', '3D', '4D', '5D', '6D', '7D', '8D', '9D', 'TD', 'JD', 'QD', 'KD',
            'AC', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', 'JC', 'QC', 'KC',
            'AH', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H', '6H', '7H', '8H', '9H', 'TH', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH',
            'AS', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', '8S', '9S', 'TS', 'JS', 'QS', 'KS'
        );



        shuffle($deck);
        $player_hand = array();
        if ($type === 'holdem')
        {

            $card_per_player = 2;
            $chunk = array_chunk($deck, $players);

            for ($j=0; $j < $players; $j++)
            { 
                for ($i=0; $i < $card_per_player; $i++)
                { 
                    array_push($player_hand, $chunk[$i][$j]);
                }
            }
            $player_hand = array_chunk($player_hand, $card_per_player);

        }

        return [$player_hand];

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:SHUFFLED DECK

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2H
        [1] => 6D
        [2] => 3D
        [3] => 2S
        [4] => 8S
        [5] => KC
        [6] => JC
        [7] => 8H
        [8] => TD
        [9] => 4S
        [10] => 7C
        [11] => KH
        [12] => 6C
        [13] => AC
        [14] => 2D
        [15] => JH
        [16] => 7D
        [17] => 9H
        [18] => 8C
        [19] => AD
        [20] => TC
        [21] => 9S
        [22] => TH
        [23] => 4C
        [24] => 6S
        [25] => 5S
        [26] => 5C
        [27] => 6H
        [28] => 4D
        [29] => KS
        [30] => JD
        [31] => KD
        [32] => TS
        [33] => QH
        [34] => 5H
        [35] => 8D
        [36] => 9C
        [37] => 5D
        [38] => 3H
        [39] => QC
        [40] => 9D
        [41] => 3S
        [42] => 7H
        [43] => QD
        [44] => 3C
        [45] => QS
        [46] => AS
        [47] => 7S
        [48] => AH
        [49] => 4H
        [50] => 2C
        [51] => JS
    )
```

PLAYERS CARDS: PLAYER = N = 3 here

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2H
                [1] => 2S
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6D
                [1] => 8S
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3D
                [1] => KC
            )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

You've already shuffled the cards, why not simply `array_chunk`?

```
shuffle($cards);
$player_card = array_chunk($cards, 13);
```

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-chunk.php

This will output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3D
        [1] => 7S
        [2] => AD
        [3] => 9C
        [4] => 5D
        [5] => KS
        [6] => 4H
        [7] => 6S
        [8] => AS
        [9] => TH
        [10] => 4S
        [11] => TS
        [12] => 3H
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => AH
        [1] => 5S
        [2] => AC
        [3] => QS
        [4] => 5H
        [5] => 7D
        [6] => JH
        [7] => QD
        [8] => JS
        [9] => 9S
        [10] => 8S
        [11] => 6C
        [12] => 2H
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => TD
        [1] => 8H
        [2] => 5C
        [3] => KD
        [4] => 8D
        [5] => QH
        [6] => JC
        [7] => TC
        [8] => 3C
        [9] => 6D
        [10] => 9H
        [11] => 2C
        [12] => 2D
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7C
        [1] => KH
        [2] => 4D
        [3] => 9D
        [4] => 6H
        [5] => 7H
        [6] => KC
        [7] => QC
        [8] => JD
        [9] => 2S
        [10] => 8C
        [11] => 4C
        [12] => 3S
    )

)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to deal the cards one by one to the players;

```
$player_card = [[],[],[],[]]; // four players
for($i = 0; i < count($deck); $i++){
    $player_card[$i % 4][] = $deck[$i];   
}
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than mine.

Comment: Now, this would not work for all card games, not even texas hold'em. Purists would also say that cards are dealt one by one to the players, not all at the same time.

Comment: Added the [] to your addition... Or else it would only keep the last card received for each player.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the logic determining which card to deal is in the inner loop, with the players loop being the outside one. Ergo, for every iteration of the outer loop, you're dealing the same card to each player.

Better would be to scrap your initial shuffle, and instead deal a random card every time, then remove that card from the master array.

```
$num_cards_to_deal = 2;
for ($k=0; $k < $players; $k++)
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_cards_to_deal; $i++) {
        $card_index = rand(0, count($deck) - 1);
        $player_card[$k][$i] = array_values($deck)[$card_index];
        unset($deck[$card_index]);
    }
```

This, however, modifies the original `$deck`, so you might want to first make a copy of it for use in the current round of dealing only.

```
$this_round_deck = $deck;
//...then replace $deck with $this_round_deck in the above code
```

Comment: this also works but: sometimes gives error:
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined offset: 32</p>
<p>Filename: models/card_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 43</p>

</div>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7H
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => JH
            [1] => KC
        )

).

see player 1's card 2 i missing. this is strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are giving out cards to players but never removing the card from the deck.

If you want to make it work like a normal deck of cards, you should always take out the top-most card. The simplest way to do it, is to use `array_shift($deck)`. It will return the first card from the array and remove it. [See details.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

To make it clean, I would create a function `draw`

```
function draw(){
    global $deck;
    return array_shift($deck);
}
```

You could create a deck class too, it would be even better as you wouldn't need to juggle with global variables, but that's for another post...

Also, if you are afraid of performances (there's no reason to be unless you are playing with a deck of a couple thousands cards), you could use array_pop() instead. It does the same thing but instead of taking the first card, takes the last card. Wouldn't change much but memory wise, it'd be easier on PHP.

Comment: Also you could use a [SplDoublyLinkedList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) that way you'd use next() to iterate over the cards without removing them, so you could keep the whole deck intact.